# minimize react-virtualzed bundle size

Tags: react-virtualized

Using browserify (commonjs), how can I minimize the size of react-virtualized? It seems to be including other classes that I'm not using like Collection and Table. I have tried using the standard syntax `import {foo, bar}...` as well as specifying each class individually `import {WindowScroller} from 'react-virtualized/dist/commonjs/WindowScroller'`. Yet it seems that RV is still taking up ~90k:

[image]
[image]
Thanks!

Comment: Is this before or after minification? If before, it wouldn't be too surprising- since `Table` (22k) includes `Grid` (40k) as well as a few utility objects. Those sizes include white space, comments, etc. though.

Comment: I'm including grid, but not table. This is after minification

Comment: RV by _itself_ is taking up 90k _after_ minification? That doesn't sound correct. The full UMD build of the library, run through a minifier, is only 103k.

Comment: Unless disc is reporting things incorrectly, it would seems to be taking up 89k

Answer (score 0):

This has been addressed in v8, where bundle sizes have been reduced